# Pass a parameterized folder name to command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I use the following command-line:

call run.bat TEST.properties

In TEST.properties file I initialize the following parameter

output.dir=C:/Test_Results

I would like the 'Test_Results' to contain a timestamp each time the script is called. How can I accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TEST.properties.bat, after

```
output.dir=C:\Test_Results
```

insert the line

```
echo %date% %time% >>%output.dir%\my_timestamps.txt
```

and the latest date/time the TEST.properties.bat is run will appear in `C:\Test_Results\my_timestamps.txt`

Note that `/` is a switch-indicator. `\` is a directory-separator.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need 1 timestamp in 'Test_Results':

```
set test=%1

rem insert timestamp generating code below if needed

set timestamp=%time%

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in (%test%) do (if "%%i"=="output.dir" echo %timestamp%>%%j)
```

If you need all the timestamps:

```
set test=%1

rem insert timestamp generating code below if needed

set timestamp=%time%

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in (%test%) do (
  if "%%i"=="output.dir" (
    if not exist %%j (echo %timestamp%>%%j) else (
      echo %timestamp%>temp.txt
      copy %%j+temp.txt %%j
      del temp.txt
    )
  )
)
```